# Is there an IP Address changed notification trigger in Task Scheduler?

Tags: windows, triggers, system, scheduled-tasks

I need to monitor a server's connection status. I should be notified by email if its ip address is changed. I have developed a console application to simply obtain the machine's public ip address and send it via email to my mailbox. Therefore, I need a trigger to call my console application and I want to do it in the windows Task Scheduler.

**Is there possible having a system trigger or event that involved in Task scheduler? And How?**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if ip helpservice is running you should have an event raised when ip change

Event ID 4200
Source:  iphlpsvc

you can create a task in win7 or win2k8 that triggers when an event occured

Comment: thank you Kayasax. I confirm your answer is working for me. Now, i don't need it to loop sending me enormous emails.

Comment: You need somehow to store the ip address and send mail only if it has changed. The address is in the event message

Comment: Can IP Helper Service log an event if the public IP changes (dynamic IP) and not the local machine's IP?